# How do I used sed to remove a whole column of data in unix?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need some help with getting rid of all the driver names from the file using a sed command. I've tried multiple different commands but I cant get it to function properly.

Input:

```
Rank Country         Driver       Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton 264 94
2 [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel      254 53
3 [Spain] Fernando_Alonso         311 32
4 [Finland] Kimi_Raikkonen        326 21
5 [Germany] Nico_Rosberg          200 23
```

I've tried using `cat f1.txt| sed -r 's/\S+//3'` but it does not keep the formatting I would like

what i would like it to do

Input:

```
Rank Country         Driver       Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom]                 264 94
2 [Germany]                        254 53
3 [Spain]                          311 32
4 [Finland]                        326 21
5 [Germany]                        200 23
```

Comment: Edit your Q to show include the command you thought should have worked. We can't help fix your understanding if we don't know where you are "at" (in regards to `sed` understanding). Good luck.

Comment: (OT: [Useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do it is just replace `$3` with spaces equal to the length of the field, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR > 1{s=sprintf("%*s", length($3) + 1, " "); sub($3,s)}1' drivers
```

The condition `FNR > 1` simply skips the 1st line in the file to preserve all headings. `+1` was added to the length of the 3rd field to match your exact output format.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR > 1{s=sprintf("%*s", length($3) + 1, " "); sub($3,s)}1' drivers
Rank Country         Driver       Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom]                 264 94
2 [Germany]                        254 53
3 [Spain]                          311 32
4 [Finland]                        326 21
5 [Germany]                        200 23
```

**Note:** If your input file actually contains `"Input:"` at the beginning, then you would use:

```
awk 'NF == 5 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]/ {s=sprintf("%*s", length($3)+1, " "); sub($3,s)}1' drivers
```

Here the condition `'NF == 5 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]/` only applies the substitution to records (lines) with five-fields beginning with a digit.

**Output**

```
$ awk 'NF == 5 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]/ {s=sprintf("%*s", length($3)+1, " "); sub($3,s)}1' drivers
Input:

Rank Country         Driver       Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom]                 264 94
2 [Germany]                        254 53
3 [Spain]                          311 32
4 [Finland]                        326 21
5 [Germany]                        200 23
```

I was unclear if that was actually part of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, this could take care of condition in case name field could have any spaces in it(and considering names wouldn't have digits in them).

```
awk '
match($0,/\] [^0-9]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  s=sprintf("%*s", length(val) + 1, " ")
  print substr($0,1,RSTART) s substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Like that approach too, Now you got it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be:

```
Rank Country         Driver       Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton 264 94
2 [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel      254 53
3 [Spain] Fernando_Alonso         311 32
4 [Finland] Kimi_Raikkonen        326 21
5 [Germany] Nico_Rosberg          200 23
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="]"}{gsub(/[[:alpha:]_]/," ",$2)}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
Rank Country         Driver       Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom]                264 94
2 [Germany]                       254 53
3 [Spain]                         311 32
4 [Finland]                       326 21
5 [Germany]                       200 23
```

Explanation: I globally replace letters and `_` with spaces which are after `]`, to do so I set field separator to `]` and use `gsub` at 2nd column i.e. everything after `]`. I also set output field separator to `]` to preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1b;:a;s/^((\S+\s+){2})[A-Z_]/\1 /i;ta' file
```

After the first line, replace the third field with spaces.

Alternative:

```
sed -E '1b;s/\S+/\n&\n/3;h;s/[^\n]/ /g;H;g;s/\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/' file
```